# Set a localStorage in a different domain

Tags: javascript, local-storage, cross-domain

I'm trying to set up a variable in a domain (like my-site.com) which I can acess from other site (like my-other-site.com). Basically, when I receive a response from my server, I want to set a variable in the localStorage and then redirect the page to the next site (e.g: in my-site.com I set the variable 'foo' and redirect the page. Inside my-other-site.com I would like to access that variable (foo)). Oh! I almost forget, I'm using Vue

I already tried to use iframe, using this tutorial (https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage). I tried some libraries like cross-storage (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-storage#overview) and biforst-cors(https://www.npmjs.com/package/bifrost-cors) but these both didn't work as I expected. I know that is possible to use query params, but I can't use it know

I have this:

```
localStorage.clear()
window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.body.data) )                                                
window.localStorage.setItem('token', response.body.token)                                                
window.location.href = `http://localhost:8081/#/` //redirect
```

Basically, I would like to user both variables user and token in other domain.

If someone could help me bringing ideias or something like that, It would help me a lot.

Comment: You can't do anything directly to some other domain. You need to communicate between them on the server, or use `postMessage()` if one page has a reference to a window or iframe containing the other.

Comment: But, can I use it when the page (the page witch I want to use those variables) is loading?

Comment: No, you can't. Every domain has its own `localStorage`. When you redirect to another domain, you have no access to the previous domain's data.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment :). I'll try to find a way to do this without queries params.

Answer (score 1):

A different solution would be this:

```
var DifferentWindow=window.open("http://www.example.com/");
DifferentWindow.localStorage.setItem("Key","Value");
```

This is in simple Javascript, so I hope it helps
What it does is open a new window with the link, and set a variable inside of that window's local storage to "value."

Comment: I get the following error when trying to set a localStorage variable for a different window: `Blocked a frame with origin "https://stackoverflow.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: This does not work, it only sets the value into the localStorage of the window that executed the script.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with **Bifrost-cors**  lib. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bifrost-cors

You have to initialize lib in both domains.
on exampleA.com
`var bifrostCors = new bifrostCors("http://exampleB.com/")`
on exampleB.com
`var bifrostCors = new bifrostCors("http://exampleA.com/")`

then you can use
`bifrostCors.setLocalStorage({key: "user", value: "persons"})`

Comment: Hi I am trying to use this but I got this error `core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: bifrostCors is not a constructor' . Do you have any idea about this

Comment: @Hasini change to new BifrostCors("http://exampleB.com/");